# Snort Rule - HTTP Body Content

Tags: snort

I am trying to create a simple rule to alert when "MZ" are the first two characters in the HTTP body.

My current rule is:

```
alert tcp any any -> any any (msg:"Test"; content:"MZ"; depth: 2; http_client_body; sid:51; rev:1;)
```

But this finds no results despite "MZ" definitely being present in the HTTP body.

Assistance much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

After seeking assistance from a few other sources, it turns out I was asking snort to look in the wrong place:

The correct rule is below:

```
alert tcp any any -> any any (msg:"Test"; file_data; content:"MZ"; depth: 2; sid:51; rev:1;)
```

Instead of `http_client_body` *after* the content string, the rule needed `file_data` *before* the content string.

`http_client_body` = the request body

`file_data` = the response body*

(*It's more complicated than that, but this is sufficient to explain this case. Please see the Snort documentation for further reference)